# Can you run Ubuntu on a TracFone LG800?

Tags: 12.04, phone

Hey I was just wondering, can I could run Ubuntu from a TracFone LG 800? It is an Android phone, so I wanted to know before I buy it.

Answer (score 1):

Since tracfone uses its os to track your wireless minute usage, it would not be a good idea to replace it with something else if you could root the device at all.

Also it's very likely the hardware is very incompatible with this phone. Android is a custom linux built for phones and not necessarily interchangeable with Ubuntu.

So no. You most likely will not be able to and keep your phone calling ability.

Comment: Are you saying you put ubuntu on android phones yourself?? From my understanding "Canonical says that Ubuntu for Android will be loaded onto phones by manufacturers, and phones will have to include USB and HDMI hardware support in order to utilize the OS. These devices aren’t yet available, but can be expected to land in late 2012" http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android

Comment: Nope, I did not say that. You are correct, you can not put ubuntu on a phone yet.